# One Hamster Needed Cage Size

Tags: hamsters

I am looking to get a hamster, but  don't know how big an aquarium has to be for one dwarf hamster. Help!

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) I've marked your question as a duplicate of an existing one. If the answer there doesn't provide you the information you need, you can edit your question to show how it is different and then we can reopen it.